# Activate traffic view in new Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps

How do I activate traffic view in new Google Maps? I can find the feature and see the color bar from fast to slow traffic view. I select traffic, but nothing happens.

Comment: Sounds like you know how to turn it on, but maybe that area isn't reporting traffic info for some reason. Can you see traffic in any other cities as a test?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you already know how to do this, but the traffic option is in the upper left hand side of your screen.

[image: Traffic option in Google Maps]

If no traffic information is showing then traffic is either not reported in your area (unlikely but not impossible) or there is an error which is preventing it from being shown. I would do the following:

1. Check back later in the day and see if it starts working again. - Could be an error on the server side which just needs a little bit of time to get resolved.
2. Restart your computer, clear cash, etc. - All the general steps to take when having a browser problem.
3. If the problem is persistent then I would [Report the problem](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/162873?hl=en).